# No values returned from function in C

Tags: c, return-value

I was trying to write a function that checks if an array has consecutive numbers (not necessarily in order), return `0` if not and `1` if yes.

For example:

```
24, 21, 22, 23
```

The return value would be `1`.

```
22,22,22
```

Would return 0.

The problem is that it return 1 for something like:

```
22,22,22
```

I could really use the help looking into it.

This is the main function (no need to check it or anything, it's fine):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Function declarations */
void Ex1();
void Ex2();
void Ex3();
void Ex4();
void Ex5();

/* Declarations of other functions */
int f3(int *, int);

/* ------------------------------- */
// 
int main() {
    int select = 0, i, all_Ex_in_loop = 0;
    printf("Run menu once or cyclically?\n"
           "(Once - enter 0, cyclically - enter other number) ");
    if (scanf_s("%d", &all_Ex_in_loop) == 1)
        do {
            for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
                printf("Ex%d--->%d\n", i, i);
            printf("EXIT-->0\n");
            do {
                select = 0;
                printf("please select 0-5 : ");
                scanf_s("%d", &select);
            } while ((select < 0) || (select > 5));
            switch (select) {
              case 1: Ex1(); break;
              case 2: Ex2(); break;
              case 3: Ex3(); break;
              case 4: Ex4(); break;
              case 5: Ex5(); break;
            }
        } while (all_Ex_in_loop && select);
    return 0;
}
```

and this is the function (UPDATED):

```
void Ex3() {
    int n, i, res;
    printf("Enter the size of the Array: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &n);
    int *arr = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    if (!arr) {
        printf("ERROR - not enough memory.");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Enter an Array >>> ");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf_s("%d", &arr[i]);
    res = f3(arr, n);
    printf("res = %d\n", res);
    free(arr);
}

int f3(int *arr, int size) {
    int i, min = arr[0], max = arr[0];
    for (i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        if (arr[i] < min)
            min = arr[i];
        if (arr[i] > max)
            max = arr[i];
    }
    int *CounterArray = (int *)calloc(max + 1, sizeof(int));
    if (!CounterArray) {
        printf("ERROR - not enough memory.");
        exit(1);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        CounterArray[arr[i]]++;
    }
    for (i = min; i <= max; i++)
        if (CounterArray[i] == 0)
            return 0;
    free(CounterArray);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: You have `free` function call after `return` statement.

Comment: You can sort the input array and then test for the consecutive predicate.

Comment: Please read about how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).
Most of the code in `main()` is irrelevant — you only need a single call `Ex3()` in it.

Comment: Are negative numbers allowed in the array?

Comment: In function `f3()`  you break the array bounds with `for (i = 1; i <= size; i++)` OK you set the min and max from element `[0]` but the upper bound breaks.

Comment: ...and then, if you want to index a status array by `max` then `calloc(max, sizeof(int));` is off by one - it needs `max+1`.

Comment: The searching loop `for (i = min; i <= max; i++) if (CounterArray[i] == 0) return 0; return 1;` is problematic.  The chances are rather good that it exits early with value 0 if the data is at all sparse.  You probably need to look to see if adjacent entries in your `CounterArray()` are non-zero, and return 1 if they are, only returning 0 if you fail to find adjacent entries.

Comment: thanks a lot!
I updated the code^

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Create yourself an answer instead.

Comment: The title does not match the problem description – it is not that 'No value is returned' but rather 'A wrong value is returned' from your function.

Comment: @Tom Is all elements required to be consecutive? Example: In `1, 4, 7, 5` the numbers 4 and 5 are consecutive so the array has consecutive numbers so the function must return 1 ... Or shall the function return 0 because 1 and 4 isn't consecutive?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- in function `f3()` you allocate an array of `max + 1` integers. This would be a problem is all numbers in the array are negative. You should instead check that `max - min + 1` is exactly the size of the array and allocate `size` elements.
- you reject the array if and only if an element in the range has a `0` count. You should instead check that all elements have a `1` count. This explains why the function fails for `22,22,22`.

Here is a modified version:

```
int f3(const int *arr, int size) {
    int result = 1;
    if (size <= 0)
        return 1;
    int i, min = arr[0], max = arr[0];
    for (i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        if (min > arr[i])
            min = arr[i];
        if (max < arr[i])
            max = arr[i];
    }
    if (max - min + 1 != size)
        return 0;
    unsigned char *CounterArray = calloc(size, sizeof(*CounterArray));
    if (!CounterArray) {
        printf("ERROR - not enough memory.");
        exit(1);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        // increment the count of this element
        if (CounterArray[arr[i] - min]++) {
            // if the count was already non zero, the test fails.
            result = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    free(CounterArray);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: @4386427: The numbers need not be in any particular order. The second loop counts the occurrences of all numbers in the array, the third checks that all numbers between `min` and `max` inclusive have a count of `1`.  `size` is also the value of `max - min + 1` as checked before allocating the array.

Comment: For all consecutive numbers between `min` and `max` to be present once in the array, its size must be `max - min + 1` :) The array is only allocated for cases like `0,0,3,3`.

Comment: @4386427: the OP is pretty clear about that: *I was trying to write a function that checks if an array has consecutive numbers (not necessarily in order)*

Comment: I deleted my own answer and my comments here as I probably misunderstood the question. A little suggestion for your solution: The `if (CounterArray[i] != 1) .....` in the last loop can be moved into the loop above, i.e. just after `CounterArray[arr[i] - min]++;`. Then the last loop can be deleted.

Comment: @4386427: good point! I was pondering about that and did not realise it would make the last loop useless. Thanks for the edit too. The array type can be smaller too.

Answer (score 0):

You return zero under the condition that

```
if (CounterArray[i] == 0)
```

but in your test case of `22,22,22` you have `min` and `max` both equal 22 and `CounterArray[22]` equal 3, not 0.

You need to re-think the condition...